# Incremental bulk insert into table with auto generated "modified date"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Right now I am doing a daily bulk insert of an csv file inside an SQL DB using the following script:

```
Truncate table [dbo].[Table];
GO

BULK INSERT [dbo].[Table]
FROM 'C:\BulkImport\Table.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n');    
GO

USE DB;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE DB  
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;  
GO  
DBCC SHRINKFILE (dbo_Log, 1);  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE DB  
SET RECOVERY FULL;  
GO
```

As you can see I am first truncating the table, then inserting the data and shrinking the log for the database (the csv file I am inserting is quite large - approx 2GB of data, and after each insert the DB size kept increasing dramatically, shrinking the log file solves this issue but I`m not sure if this is good practice or not, I am fairly new to the SQL world).

Now I want to achieve 2 things:

- I realize that truncating the whole table and inserting back the data in the csv file is not good practice, so now I want to bulk insert the file inside the database incrementally, only for new or modified data (part of the data in the file changes retroactively).
- to have created / modified date columns generated automatically upon inserting / updating data.

Comment: I believe shrinking is frowned upon, but looking at that code maybe set simple recovery before you do the bulk insert.; hasn't all the data been loaded in before that. Also will the csv file always have all the data or will it be just updates? e.g. day one initial load, and subsequent days just the data that has changed. Otherwise I imagine you would have to put the data from the CSV into a staging table and then use the MERGE Command. Or maybe this is calling for a SSIS project implementation where you create a workflow (Im not to clued up on the SSIS side, seems very click orientated).

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you, I will try setting the recovery to simple before the bulk insert. The csv has all the data, I could output only new data (including retroactive new data) but that would take more processing time on a server that has many other tasks. I would prefer the SQL server doing all the updating in the table. I will look at the MERGE command. Any ideas regarding the created / modified timestamp columns?

Comment: Using the MERGE you will need a unique identifier that being an number, guid or composite of columns that you know will be unique. Once you have this when you use the MERGE you can do inserts for no matches and hence set the created date and modified date to now. Otherwise if it is found then you know to only update the modified date. https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-sql-merge-statement/